# Extract part of text from meta using Zapier code action (javascript)

Tags: zapier

I want to extract part of a long meta paragraph.  It appears like this, but longer:

> Full Bar Review item_meta: {u'Location': u'NYU PM (Live)', u'Law School': u'Albany Law School', u'1st-time-taking-a-bar-review-course': u'Yes, this is my first time'}

I simply want to output the value `Albany Law School` or one of 300 other options that may appear there.

This is where I need to add the code in Zapier: [Zapier Action Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/52cWc.png)

Thank you.

Comment: What is the URL for the `Code documentation for more information` link seen in your screenshot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just published a tutorial about this very problem.

You can see it at http://zapiertutorials.com/2016/03/17/extract-data-from-a-long-string-of-text-using-formatter-or-code-in-zapier/

Comment: Thanks Regan. This is exactly what I needed. The formatter did not work for me, maybe because my data comes in on multiple lines, and not as a block of text. But the javascript did work great. Thank you for this.

Comment: I do have one small issue with the javascript that you may have a solution for. Sometimes the data has the value it is looking for and sometimes it does not. So if I am extracting email and the email does not exist, it still returns a value. Maybe 10 characters from somewhere random in the data. Is there maybe a way to add a "if piece of data does not exist return nothing"?

Comment: That website is trying to trick users into installing a Chrome extension.